# startup and kill scripts fails

Tags: linux, centos

I have a custom bash scripts in RHEL6 which linked to start and kill scripts K99stop and S99start .
start up script (S99script) works fine without any issue but K99stop is not being executed while shutting down or reboot.
Please help me to make it execute while reboot or shutdown.

```
start() {
    echo start >> /tmp/test
    # start application command
}

# stop function will be executed on shutdown
stop() {
    echo stop >> /tmp/test
    # stop application command
}
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/test
case "$1" in
start)
    touch ${LOCKFILE}
    start
    ;;
stop)
    rm ${LOCKFILE}
    stop
    ;;
*)
    echo "invalid argument"
    exit 1
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet it works, but you can't see it just because /tmp and /var/lock/subsys may be cleared on reboot. Check it, please, or try set "lock" and "test" files in another places.